# Sharepoint Online List column link to folder in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I'm trying to have a column in my list that links to a folder in my document library which has a name that matches the Quote number of the item.

So my list has the columns 'Name', 'Customer', 'Quote Number'
and inside my document library, inside a folder called Quotes, I have a folder for each quote number. How can I link the two together?

Answer (score 0):

Cool I got it:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "Name for HyperLink",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='https://sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/firstFolderName/' + [$Quote_x0020_Number]"
   }
}
```